# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$category

Tags: php, laravel

I have a filters table.

[image: filters]

categories table

[image: categories]

I want to get the name of the category table and display it on the filters index page.

[image: filters table]

Because I created one category (ie phone accessories). So I have to show this. How can I display from the Filter model? Not from the Category model. Filter model only. Because I want to edit and delete it later.

FilterController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $filters = Filter::with('category')->latest()->paginate(25);
    return  view('Admin.filters.index', compact('filters'));
}
```

Filter.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($filters->category as $filter)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $filter->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $filter->name }}</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                <a href="{{ route('filters.edit', $filter->id) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">edit</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="{{ route('filters.destroy', $filter->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteFilter" onclick="loadDeleteModal(`{{ $filter->name }}`)" data-id="{{ $filter->id }}">remove</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I see this error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$category (View: C:\xampp8\htdocs\projects\digikala\laravel7\resources\views\Admin\filters\index.blade.php)

Comment: `$filters` is a collection of models and each of those models has a single category so `$filters->category` does not exist on this collection. It's not clear what you're trying to display here.

Comment: I'm trying to display here for example phone accessories

Comment: So basically all categories?

Comment: All categories stored in the filter table

Comment: So basically all results from `Category::has('filters')` assuming you set up the inverse relationship between categories and filters?

Comment: @apokryfos  Yes ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display all categories that are attached to any filter you can do so using:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::has('filters')->paginate(25);
    return  view('Admin.filters.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <a href="{{ route('categories.edit', $category->id) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">edit</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="{{ route('categories.destroy-with-filters', $category->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteFilter" onclick="loadDeleteModal(`{{ $category->name }}`)" data-id="{{ $category->id }}">remove</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Note this assumes the edit and remove button are there to edit and remove the categorie and you have a `route('categories.destroy-with-filters', $category->id)` defined which removes both the category and associated filters either via an `ON DELETE CASCADE` or manually.

Answer (score 1):

are you paginating filters or categories?

In your query, you are paginating filters model, but in your blade, you are looping categories.

The code should have been like the following, if you want to access filter properties

```
@foreach($filters as $filter)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $filter->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $filter->name }}</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <a href="{{ route('filters.edit', $filter->id) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">edit</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="{{ route('filters.destroy', $filter->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteFilter" onclick="loadDeleteModal(`{{ $filter->name }}`)" data-id="{{ $filter->id }}">remove</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

If you want to access the category properties

```
@foreach($filters as $filter)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $filter->category->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $filter->category->name }}</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <a href="{{ route('filters.edit', $filter->id) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">edit</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="{{ route('filters.destroy', $filter->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteFilter" onclick="loadDeleteModal(`{{ $filter->name }}`)" data-id="{{ $filter->id }}">remove</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please look at `fillters` table, TThis table has a `category_id`, I have the number 11 as one, So it should show a row. Your code now displays two rows.